# VBA Function To Test String For Abbreviations

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following function (UDF) which does exactly what I want, however I'm wondering whether it's possible without a dictionary (array with pre defined abbreviations )? The function converts a string to propercase ignoring the abbreviations (always uppercase). I want the function to be dynamic, so that I dont have to change the abbreviations in the array each time my data changes (the number of abbreviations could grow considerably). Is this possible?

```
Public Function PROPERCASE(s As String)
'Variables
Dim bResult      As Boolean
Dim i            As Integer, j As Integer
Dim c            As Variant, v As Variant

c = Array("ENIS", "ENIR", "PCS", "WFC", "MBS", "SIE", "SCI", "TCS", "I/O", "SNMP", _
            "RX", "TX", "PSU", "UPS", "UHF", "FXO", "FXS", "VOIP", "TIN", "NMS", _
            "AC", "DC", "VRS", "TETRA", "NTP", "PoE", "TEMPEST")     'Abbreviations to ignore

v = Split(Replace(s, "/", " / "), " ")        'Separates the words

For j = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
    For i = LBound(c) To UBound(c)
        If StrComp(Replace(Replace(v(j), "(", ""), ")", ""), c(i), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Or (v(j) Like "*#*") Then bResult = True: Exit For Else bResult = False
    Next i
    If bResult = False Then v(j) = StrConv(v(j), vbProperCase): bResult = False
Next j

PROPERCASE = Replace(Join(v, " "), " / ", "/")        'Joins the words
End Function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `s`, please? Can you show us how the argument string looks?

Comment: How exactly would this be "dynamic"? Would you pass it an additional argument, perhaps a `Range` containing the abbreviations to ignore? That'd be pretty easy.

Comment: How about just checking `If v(j) = UCase(v(j))` and skip that word if true?  edit - nevermind I see you have one mixed-case term in your list.

Comment: s="REMOVE & REPLACE CORE SWITCH (ENIS) ASSEMBLY" as an example.

Comment: By dynamic I mean I dont have to write a list of abbreviations to ignore.

Comment: @coombech Do you mean you want your code to ignore certain abbreviations, but you don't want to have to tell your code exactly what to ignore? How would you expect it to know without either a list or a pattern?